# Need advices on OOP PHP MySQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

So I wrote a simple MySQLi class (scratched from different tutorials + my own knowledge) and I'd like you to point out any errors and/or what should I add/change/remove. Big thanks. Here's the code:

**dbclass.php**

```
<?php
    class Database
    {
        protected static $connection;

        public function __construct()
        {
            self::$connection = $this->connect();
        }

        public function __destruct()
        {
            self::$connection->close();
        }

        private function connect()
        {
            if (!isset(self::$connection))
            {
                $config = parse_ini_file("dbsettings.ini");
                self::$connection = new mysqli($config["host"], $config["username"], $config["password"], $config["database"]);
            }

            if (!self::$connection)
                return false;

            return self::$connection;
        }   

        public function query($query)
        {
            $result = self::$connection->query($query);
            return $result;
        }  

        public function select($query)
        {
            $rows = array();
            $result = $this->query($query);

            if (!$result)
                return false;

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

            return $rows;
        } 

        public function escape($value)
        {
            $value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            return "'".self::$connection->real_escape_string($value)."'";
        }
    };
?>
```

**Example usage**

```
<?php
    require("php/require/dbclass.php");

    if (isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
        $conn = new Database;

        $email = $conn->escape($_POST["email"]);
        $password = $conn->escape($_POST["password"]);

        $rows = $conn->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $email");

        if ($rows)
        {
            foreach ($rows as $row)
            {
                echo $row["username"]."<br />";
            }
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: First advice - learn about __prepared statements__

Comment: Are you trying to make your dbclass a singleton class??

Comment: Do you get errors yourself?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code review site, but one feedback is essential: anything that doesn't have a support for **prepared statements** should never be used.

Comment: @chris85 it won't cause an error

Comment: Why wrap a perfectly usable class in another class. All you are doing is obfiscating well know methods and property names with unknow method and property names!

Comment: @chris85 why should it cause an error? email is a field in the table **users**, $email is a value from `$_POST`

Comment: @chris85 no, if you read this code

Comment: @RiggsFolly to stop writing x lines of code on each page if I want to make a query, the class makes it simpler and less code

Comment: @daavid245 as you can learn from my answer, your class is doing quite the opposite ;)

Comment: But my **escape** function returns **' + variable + '** already, look closely :)

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Oh, thats your own escape function..

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow is not a code review site but still. Isn't it better to make your code to do escaping for you? Are you sure you want write that escape call by hand for every single variable (with a risk of *forgetting* that), instead of just a simple line like this

```
    $conn = new Database;
    $rows = $conn->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [$_POST["email"]]);
```

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks :)